# Adding Parent field in create query with Rally

Tags: rally

I am trying to add a "parent" field which consists of parent's formatted ID in rally. The parent pre-exists in Rally. I just need to know how I should add a user story with it's parent ID. I also referred to this link https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby/tree/master/examples

Here's my query.

```
child_array["Name"] = info["Name"]
child_array["Description"] = info["Description"]
child_array["ScheduleState"] = info["Schedule State"]
child_array["ParentID"] = info["Parent"]
puts "Child array parent #{child_array["ParentID"]}" #this correctly prints parentID

create_story = @rally.create("hierarchicalrequirement",child_array)
```

Please share any information you have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to associate a story to a Parent in Rally, you would need to assign the value of the "Parent" field to be the _ref of the Parent Story. You can do this by either querying for the Parent story, or assigning the _ref directly, if you already know it. Here's an example:

```
parent_formatted_id = "US43"
parent_story_query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()

parent_story_query.query_string        = "(FormattedID = #{parent_formatted_id})"
parent_story_query.type                = "hierarchicalrequirement"
parent_story_query.fetch               = "ObjectID,FormattedID,Name"
parent_story_query.project_scope_up    = false
parent_story_query.project_scope_down  = true
parent_story_query.order               = "FormattedID Asc"

parent_story_results = @rally.find(parent_story_query)
if parent_story_results.total_result_count > 0 then
    parent_story = parent_story_results.first

    child_story_fields = {}
    child_story_fields["Name"] = "Sample Child Story"
    child_story_fields["Parent"] = parent_story
    # The following would also work, if you know the ref of the parent story
    # child_story_fields["Parent"] = "/hierarchicalrequirement/12345678910"

    new_child_story = @rally.create("hierarchicalrequirement", child_story_fields)
    new_child_story.read
    puts "Created New Child Story: #{new_child_story.FormattedID}; Parented to --> #{parent_story.FormattedID}"
end
```

Comment: can I add the ref to the parent field directly? For example:
child_story_fields["Parent"] = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/hierarchicalrequirement/12345678910.js"

what do you think about it?

Comment: I tried doing it your way, here's my function 
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6199078/

But it still doesn't work. The info contains all the values. I got the _ref of parent and attached it to child_story_fields["Parent"] as you can see in the code. I also tried it the other way by assigning the Rally Object to the parent field. But neither worked.

Comment: You're assigning your values to a "ParentID" field - there's no such field in Rally. The field is called "Parent".

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thanks for your help & sorry to comment about it on github. I will keep that in mind! Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear it's working. No problem about Github. Stackoverflow works well for this kind of Q&A. Cheers!

Comment: can you also help me with this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325098/rally-updating-team-members-to-project
Thanks!